# openGL-drawing using unsigned int coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been trying to draw points with unsigned integer coordinates
However, whenever I do one point is drawn at the center and the next at the far right, I cannot see any of the other points (except the first and second from the next line). Is there any way to fix this without converting to floats?

My draw code is as follows:

```
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vbo);
SDL_GL_SwapWindow(_window);

glPointSize(1);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_TRUE, 0, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, _dataCount);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

**EDIT:**

I have determined that it is related to the gl_Position.w value in the vertex shader, can anyone tell me how to use this correctly?

**EDIT 2:**
I have distributed the values between 0 and _maxValue (largest unsigned int for the moment), and set that to be gl_Position.w, for the moment it draws to the screen but only in the upper left quadrant, I would assume this is because it is being mapped to 0.0-1.0 instead of -1.0-1.0. How do you fix this issue?

Alternatively I feel I should be doing something with the projection matrix, I haven't needed to use it before as I'm relatively new to openGL, so I'm not sure exactly what I specifically need if this is the correct approach, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Should I be doing something to the vertex shader or something to do with my initialization of the display?

Comment: check if _dataCount has the correct value, sometimes you might just draw a part of the total vertices.

Comment: _dataCount is correct, I have converted it to normalized floats before and it draws correctly but  I need to draw it as unsigned int. What do you mean when you say what is my data, If you mean what does it contain, that is just coordinate data, one point for every location on the screen.

Comment: Should I be distributing the values evenly between 0 and the max unsigned int or just leave them as the initial values(pixel coordinates)?